# Whats the best way to scale down a background image for mobiles?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a large good quality BG image which scales down on smaller devices.

Currently the browser width is detected then an image handler generates the BG image for that screen size, which makes it nice and small on mobiles.

The problem is when the user resizes the window. I have something in place which detects the browser width again upon resize and then replaces the image. The problem is that there is flickering when the user resizes so it doesn't look great.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you resize them on every pixel the user resizes the browser? I would propably define 3 states and only replace the image when the user changes his state (size in other state).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a resizable BG image that scales down this should do the work:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gcmkw

HTML

```
<div class="bg-image">
  <img src="http://mypages.valdosta.edu/asmccoy/Great-Mountains-mountains-and-waterfalls-9842020-1920-1440.jpg" alt="" />  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bg-image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to generate a new one based on browser width in order to reduce the size

Comment: Got it. Just to understand, you're doing that just to make the image file size smaller or for another reason? If that's the case maybe you could pre-define 4 screen widths, serve only those 4 sizes, and for smaller screens resize.